# jQuery css border fadeout effect on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div that I can drag and sort using jQuery sortable. The div contains a child div which has a grey border and when the dragging starts I change the border color to blue by adding a css class "mybox-on-drag". Then when the dragging stops, I toggle it to remove the class.

Now, during the stop function how do I fade out the blue color and back to grey?

```
            start: function(event, ui) {
                    ui.item.children("#mybox").toggleClass("mybox-on-drag");
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                    ui.item.children("#mybox").toggleClass("mybox-on-drag");
            }
```

Thank you.

Comment: you may have to use something like jquery color http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/24/jquery-color-2-1-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with an CSS3-Only Solution, try the new [transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)-Feature (not supported in older browsers).

Otherwise, try to set the color with jQuery using the [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) Function.

```
ui.item.children("#mybox").animate({border-color: "#efefef"}, 500);
```

EDIT: For the jquery Solution, you need jQuery colors, as stated in the comment!

Comment: what are the older browsers that are not supported? thank you for your answer.

Comment: On the linked CSS3-Spec-Page is a good Browser-Support table.Mainly, these are IE<9.0, Chrome<26.0, FF<16.0, Safari<6.1.